# Is there a native way to disable grant_types_supported in IdentityServer4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

Currently, I'm using the following:

```
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
    {
        options.Discovery.ShowGrantTypes = false;
        options.Discovery.CustomEntries.Add("grant_types_supported", new [] {"client_credentials"});
    })
```

The resulting discovery data at `/.well-known/openid-configuration` looks correct, but I am hoping to find a less hack-ish way of configuring this. All of our authentication/authorization will be server-to-server using client_credentials.

Comment: Why do you care? It is just the discovery document. It is not that you actually *disable* the grant type with that.

Comment: Ideally I'd like to disable those grant types and have the discovery document reflect that, just haven't been able to figure out how.

Comment: You can't disable them. But you cannot use them (meaning no client is configured to use them).

Comment: Oh well, thanks for the feedback anyways!